Characterizing the level sets of a continuously differentiable $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with finitely many critical points
Let $n$ be any positive integer and $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a very well-behaved function in the sense that

$f$ is continuously differentiable.
$f$ has a finite amount of critical points.
For every sequence of $x_\kappa$ such that $\vert \vert x_\kappa \vert \vert \to \infty$, we have $f(x_\kappa) \to \infty$.

Let $K \in \text{Im}(f)$. It seems to me that $f^{-1}(K)$ is a finite disjoint union of some connected sets $C_1, \dots, C_k$. I've done some tests for $n=2, 3$ and it also seems that for $n>1$ each $C_i$ is a compact set that can be categorized as one of the following three types:

$C_i$ consists of a single critical point of $f$. This critical point is either a local min or a local max.
$C_i$ is an $n-1$ dimensional manifold. Also, there is a critical point which is either a local min or a local max "strictly inside" $C_i$.
$C_i$ is the union of sets $D_1, \dots, D_j$ such that each $D_i$ is an $n-1$ dimensional manifold, $D_i \bigcap D_j$ is either a singleton or the  empty set (when $i \neq j$) and if it is a singleton, then this element is a saddle point of $f$.

Additionally, another way saddle points can be formed is when a $D_i$ is like this (although I'm not sure how I would describe it):

(taken from here)
Is this really true? If it isn't, is there some extra condition that makes it true?

This is quite false already in the case $n=2$: the number of components can be infinite and they can be unbounded.

Could you please provide an example? Also, what if $f$ additionally satisfies the following property: for every sequence $x_\kappa \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\vert \vert x_\kappa \vert \vert \to \infty$ we have $f(x_\kappa) \to \infty$?

As an example take $Re(\exp(z)), z\in \mathbb C$. Yes, properness will help, but, I think, you need a Morse function (nondegenerate critical points).

However, there is absolutely no reason to expect that regular level sets of $f$ are disjoint unions of spheres (once $n\ge 3$). For instance, on $\mathbb R^3$ you can find proper Morse functions with regular level sets of arbitrary genus.

That's true. Now that I think about, I don't want a homeomorphism to $S^{n-1}$. I just wnat it to be an $n-1$ dimensional manifold. I've now edited my question.

You should add the assumption that $f$ is Morse (generic functions are). Even then, critical level sets are more complicated than you expect, you should read about Morse theory to understand what do they look like (they have isolated quadratic singularities). Start by reading the Wikipedia article.

I see, I'll read about it, thanks!
